# ServiceStack.Text json deserialization creates wrong object instead of throwing on invalid json input string

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

When I try to deserialise this invalid json string ( `}]` missing in the end) :

```
[{"ExtId":"2","Name":"VIP sj�lland","Mobiles":["4533333333","4544444444"]
```

By doing this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(str);
```

The ServiceStack json deserializer accepts the string, but it creates a wrong object, because I end up with a C# object having these values:

```
ExtId : "2"                                      // ok fine.
Name: "VIP sj�lland"                            // ok fine
Mobiles: ["4533333333","4544444444", "544444444"]// Aarg! An array with 3 objects ?!? 
                                                 // There were only two in the JSON string.
```

In this case it would be much better to have an exception thrown instead of continuing with bad data. Therefore I tried using:

```
JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;
```

just before calling DeserializeFromString but no exception was thrown. In January I asked this question [Configure ServiceStack.Text to throw on invalid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972556/configure-servicestack-text-to-throw-on-invalid-json) and the answer was that ServiceStack is favoring resilence and that I could make a pull request in GitHub.

Is this still the case? And have anyone done it already, saving me the trouble? Otherwise, I am on a very tight schedule, so if anyone has some code or suggestions for how to create an option-flag for making ServiceStack throw on deserialization errors, please reply here, so that I can get this done faster.

Comment: I saw your original post, I agree you should at least have an option to turn strict json validation on. I get the same results by switching back to the Newtonsoft serializer. As one of my colleges pointed out if we use resilient serialization we are going back down the same road of allowing rubbish html to be parsed without errors where it allows for sloppy developers.

Comment: This just looks like a bug.  Have you filed [an issue for it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/new)?

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved in ServiceStack.Text **v4+** which by default doesn't populate incomplete collections, e.g:

```
public class Poco
{
    public string ExtId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Mobiles { get; set; }
}

var json = "[{\"ExtId\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"VIP sj�lland\",\"Mobiles\":[\"4533333333\",\"4544444444\"]";

var dto = json.FromJson<Poco[]>();

Assert.That(dto[0].ExtId, Is.EqualTo("2"));
Assert.That(dto[0].Name, Is.EqualTo("VIP sj�lland"));
Assert.That(dto[0].Mobiles, Is.Null);
```

Or if preferred can throw on Error:

```
JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;

Assert.Throws<SerializationException>(() => 
    json.FromJson<Poco[]>());
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is a little bit picky when it comes to JSON. Following would be **valid**! Note i do not have anonymous object array as the default element.

```
{
    "ExtItem": [
        {
            "ExtId": "2",
            "Name": "VIPsj�lland",
            "Mobiles": [
                "4533333333",
                "4544444444"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If i generate a POCO from this I get

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Extitem[] ExtItem { get; set; }
}

public class Extitem
{
    public string ExtId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Mobiles { get; set; }
}
```

I personally use extension method to string

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public  static bool DeserializeJson<T>(this String str, out T item)
    {
        item = default(T);
        try
        {
            item = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(str);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This would enable me to write:

```
Rootobject ext;
const string validJson = @"
{
    ""ExtItem"": [
        {
            ""ExtId"":""2"",
            ""Name"":""VIPsj�lland"",
            ""Mobiles"":[
                ""4533333333"",
                ""4544444444""
            ]
        }
    ]
}";
if (validJson.DeserializeJson(out ext))
{ //valid input 
    // following would print 2 elements : 4533333333, 4544444444
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ext.ExtItem.First().Mobiles)); 
} //invalid input
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this an have the exception thrown when I missed the } at the end.

In C#, the format for JSON is {"name", "value"}  not [{"name", "value"}].

```
class M
        {
            public string ExtId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<string> Mobiles { get; set; }
        }

string str = "{\"ExtId\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"VIP\",\"Mobiles\":[\"4533333333\",\"4544444444\"]";

M m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M>(str);
```

When run this, you will get error as a } is missing.

Using:

```
string str = "{\"ExtId\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"VIP\",\"Mobiles\":[\"4533333333\",\"4544444444\"]}";
```

The object is deserialized fine.

You can see the JSON of this object from:

```
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use the `Newtonsoft.Json` `T JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string value)` and it throws an exception;

If I use the `object JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value)` this one it creates the correct object by simply placing the missing `}]`

I found that this is a very reliable and fast library.