# ServiceStack converts invalid values into null instead of throwing ValidationException

Tags: servicestack

Lets say that we have the following request object:

```cs
public class UserRequest
{
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool DeservesGift { get; set; }
}
```

And try to post the following json to the given url:

```json
{ 
    "Birthday": "A late summer night",
    "DeservesGift": "No way!"
}
```

I would expect an exception of some kind. Instead, the service receives a `UserRequest` instance with `null` for Birthday and `false` for DeservesGift.

Why is this?
How can we know if they tried to set the Birthday to null, which should result in a 200 ok, versus an attempt to set it to something else, which should result in a 400 Bad request? Cause now we will set the birthday to null and respond 200 ok, and that ain't right...

Comment: Since you tagged servicestack I'm assuming you're using ServiceStack.Text. Take a look at this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972556/configure-servicestack-text-to-throw-on-invalid-json

Comment: It seams like the problems are related. In the answer that you link to, @Mythz suggest that someone make a pull request to offer the the option that I eventually found on JsConfig.

Answer (score 1):

The static object `JsConfig` has a property `ThrowOnDeserializationError` which defaults to false. Setting it to true will cause a `SerializationException` in the examples above.

[JsConfig.cs, line 343->:](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L343)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating if the framework should throw serialization exceptions
    /// or continue regardless of deserialization errors. If <see langword="true"/>  the framework
    /// will throw; otherwise, it will parse as many fields as possible. The default is <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool? sThrowOnDeserializationError;
    public static bool ThrowOnDeserializationError { }
```